# could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation

Tags: hadoop

I set up hadoop on two clusters, and In the master node when I tried to put file using:
`hadoop fs -put test.txt /mydata/`
I got the following error:

```
put: File /mydata/test.txt._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 0 datanode(s) running and 0 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

When I typed `hdfs dfsadmin -report` it gave me the following information:

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Replicated Blocks:
    Under replicated blocks: 0
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
    Low redundancy block groups: 0
    Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
    Missing block groups: 0
    Low redundancy blocks with highest priority to recover: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
```

Then when I tried to access hdfs from datanode with `hadoop fs -ls /` it gives me the following information:

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/172.31.81.91:10001. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
```

I set up the instance on 2 aws-ubuntu instances and opened all TCP/IPV4 ports. I have the following setups:

On two setups:

### core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://172.31.81.91:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

### hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </property>

  <property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/namenode </value>
   </property>

   <property>
      <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
      <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoopinfra/hdfs/datanode </value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

### mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
            <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
            <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
            <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

### /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.31.81.91 master
172.31.45.232 slave-1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

### workers

```
172.31.45.232
```

And when I type `jps` I can get

### master

```
12532 NameNode
12847 SecondaryNameNode
13599 Jps
```

### datanode

```
5172 Jps
4810 DataNode
```

When I type `sudo netstat -ntlp` I can get:

### master:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9870            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12532/java          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      696/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1106/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      809/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 172.31.81.91:9000       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12532/java          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9868            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12847/java          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1176/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1106/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      809/cupsd
```

### datanode:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9864            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4810/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9866            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4810/java           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9867            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4810/java           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      691/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1142/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      854/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45029         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4810/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1142/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      854/cupsd
```

I am using hadoop 3.1.3, any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your datanode is unable to register itself with the namenode. Check for errors in both namenode and datanode logs. Also please confirm whether you have the `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` files in both the nodes

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer from myself...After many tries

1. If using AWS, all ip should be public IPs.
2. in core-site.xml, use the public dns instead of IP
3. delete the data node file after format. Not sure why... But this really solve my problem.

Thanks for help!